# blue highlight when clicking button jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile project.

There are buttons ans links in the app, and I want the blue background on alls buttons!

There are two kinds of buttons : buttons with links

```
<a id="cancel" href="http://path" data-role="button" data-icon="cancel" data-inline="true">CANCEL</a>
```

Those kinds of button works fine (blue when clicked)

And those buttons :

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" data-role="button" data-icon="ok" data-inline="true" />
```

And those submit doesn't work. They are in POST Form.

I want to make the button blue when I click on them. Actually, There is a shade around but no blue button :

[image: Shade] (just the shade... The button must be all blue ^^ )

How to make this button be blue ?!?

Thanks to help me !

**EDIT :**

I tried `class="ui-btn-active"` on the input too, but the button is still grey

Comment: Perhaps adding a `href="javascript:void(0)"` might help? Alternatively can you perhaps post a jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: what do you want exactly? blue shadow around buttons or blue button on click?

Comment: @Omar : Blue button ! the blue shadow is the curent effect but I just want blue button when pressed (and the blue button still untill the new page)

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dhSfd/

Comment: `input` is different than `a` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yp9yw/

Comment: @Omar : yes but the button must still blue after the click too! And the button must be a input type = submit, not a link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` with type `submit` is wrapped in a div, so you need `ui-btn-active` to parent div of submit button.

```
$(this).closest('div').addClass("ui-btn-active");
```

For anchors with `data-role="button"`

```
$(this).addClass("ui-btn-active");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yp9yw/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS,

Then use `background-color` for them.

```
a:active, input[type="submit"]:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I have created a fiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/kMm3W/. The issue there is the JS version (jQuery Mobile) its the code from them, you're not making any mistake. You can see jQuery Mobile checked at the left side. If you uncheck it, you will see the background. So, you will need to change that.

This problem arises in jQuery Mobile 1.3.xx not in 1.2. So this is an edition in the code, to make the UI similar cross browser.

Comment: ok thanks, but when the user click on the button, the background-button must have to still blue but little bit css must be ok. I really think there is a JQUERRY solution with a tag or something like that but this is a little bit dirty solution but working !

Comment: Yes, this is the only thing that you can do while having the jQuery Mobile. Because this case arose in jQuery Mobile 1.3 Which is to just make the look of the web page alike.